# How to get rid of "Send Empty Value" checkbox in Swagger UI?

Tags: swagger, swagger-ui

[image]Does anyone know how to get rid of "Send Empty Value" checkbox in Swagger UI?

Comment: This checkbox is displayed if the form fields are defined as optional, it controls whether the fields without values are sent as `name=` or not sent at all. See https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/issues/5303 where this feature was requested. Is there a specific reason you want to remove this checkbox?

Comment: This checkbox is showing for specific api's only, so we want to totally remove this option.

Answer (score 1):

In the body of the schema, set the `required` parameter to contain the properties you want to set as required.

Example:

```
CreateTranscriptionPayload:
  type: object
  required: ['audioFile']
  properties:
    audioFile:
      type: string
      format: binary
      description: MP3 or WebM audio file.
```